# Getting wrong results in post synthesis simulation

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

I am writing a code for Matrix Transpose in VHDL i am taking input in row major and one element of matrix per every clock cycle and i store the data in column major format after that i send tha data in coloumn major format element by element every clock cycle to the output . The code is as below it is simulating properly but the post synthesis results are not right can anyone plz help how to synthesize code to get correct results

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity Matrix_Trans_Sysgen is
generic(n: integer :=3);
port (my_clk : in std_logic;
my_ce : in std_logic;
input_matrix : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
output_matrix : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)
);
end Matrix_Trans_Sysgen;

architecture Behavioral of Matrix_Trans_Sysgen is

type t1 is array (natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

signal a : t1((n*n)-1 downto 0) :=(others => (others =>'0'));

signal output_there : std_logic :='0';

signal x : integer range 0 to 2*n :=0;
signal y : integer range 0 to 2*n :=0;
signal z : integer range 0 to 2*n*n :=0;

begin

----- Process to take all input_matrix into array
process(my_clk,input_matrix,x,y)
begin

if(x < n) then

    if(y < n) then
       if(rising_edge(my_clk)) then 
          a(y*n+x) <= input_matrix;
          y <= y+1;
       end if;
    else
      x<=x+1;
      y<=0;
    end if;
  else
    output_there <= '1';

end if;
end process;


----- Process to send all output elements through port
process(my_clk,z,output_there)
begin

if (output_there = '1') then

    if(z < n*n) then


      if(rising_edge(my_clk)) then


         output_matrix <= a(z);
         z<=z+1;

      end if;

    end if;

end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Thanks and Regards

Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite it using the usual template for clocked processes. That is, with

"`if rising_edge(clk) then ...` "

outermost in the process. Synthesis tools look for this construct and handle it correctly; other forms of process can confuse the tools.